# Adding links to changing images

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So I'm making a page that an image is displayed and every 2 seconds, the image changes using four images within an array.  I also need to be able to link each image to a different url, however I'm not sure how to do this as everything I've tried hasn't worked, any help is greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <script src = "task6.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="ImageChange()">
<div align="center">
<img src="images/image2.png" id="image" height="200" width="200">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var Cntr = 2;

var images = new Array();
images[0] = "images/image1.png";
images[1] = "images/image2.png";
images[2] = "images/image3.png";
images[3] = "images/image4.png";

function ImageChange()
{
Cntr= Cntr+1;
if (Cntr==4)
{
    Cntr=0;
}
document.getElementById("image").src=images[Cntr];
setTimeout("ImageChange()", 2000);
}
```

Comment: 'Link each image' how? Do you mean updating the `src`, or creating an `a` element that can be clicked on?

Comment: You can do it as you are doing with the images, put an anchor tag `<a>` wrapping the image tag `<img>`. Then in your `Javascript` you can create another `array` with the links that you need and change it as you do with the images.

Comment: adding a hyperlink to each image so an 'a' element

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
var Cntr = 2;

var images = new Array();
images[0] = "<a href=\"http://google.com/\"><img src=\"images/image1.png\" height=\"200\" width=\"200\"></a>";
images[1] = "<a href=\"http://bing.com/\"><img src=\"images/image2.png\" height=\"200\" width=\"200\"></a>";
images[2] = "<a href=\"http://facebook.com/\"><img src=\"images/image3.png\" height=\"200\" width=\"200\"></a>";
images[3] = "<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/\"><img src=\"images/image4.png\" height=\"200\" width=\"200\"></a>";

function ImageChange()
{
Cntr= Cntr+1;
if (Cntr==4)
{
    Cntr=0;
}
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=images[Cntr];
setTimeout("ImageChange()", 2000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <script src = "task6.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="ImageChange()">
<div align="center">
<div id="container"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your link in A tag

Like this

```
<a href="" id="mylink"><img src="images/image2.png" id="image" height="200" width="200"></a>
```

and change your javascript like below.

```
var Cntr = 2;

var images = new Array();
images[0] = "images/image1.png";
images[1] = "images/image2.png";
images[2] = "images/image3.png";
images[3] = "images/image4.png";

var links = new Array();
links[0] = "link1";
links[1] = "link2";
links[2] = "link3";
links[3] = "link4";

function ImageChange()
{
Cntr= Cntr+1;
if (Cntr==4)
{
    Cntr=0;
}
document.getElementById("image").src=images[Cntr];
document.getElementById("mylink").href=links[Cntr];
setTimeout("ImageChange()", 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply like that. In html,

```
<body onload="ImageChange()">
<div align="center">
    <a href="www.gotoone.com" id="link">
        <img src="images/image1.png" id="image" height="200" width="200">
    </a>
</div>
```

In javascript,

```
var Cntr = 2;

var images = [
    {img : "images/image1.png", link : 'www.gotoone.com'},
    {img : "images/image2.png", link : 'www.gotootwo.com'},
    {img : "images/image3.png", link : 'www.gotothree.com'},
    {img : "images/image4.png", link : 'www.gotofour.com'},
];


function ImageChange()
{
    Cntr= Cntr+1;
    if (Cntr==4)
    {
        Cntr=0;
    }

    document.getElementById("image").src=images[Cntr].img;
    document.getElementById("link").href=images[Cntr].link;
    setTimeout("ImageChange()", 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

**Markup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <script src = "task6.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="ImageChange(0)">
<div align="center">
    <a id="yourLink" href="http::// www.google.com">
        <img src="img/google.png" />
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var link = document.getElementById("yourLink"),
    image = link.getElementsByTagName("img")[0],
    images = [{
        image: 'url1.png', href: 'url1.com'
    }, {
        image: 'url2.png', href: 'url2.com'
    }, {
        image: 'url3.png', href: 'url3.com'
    }, {
        image: 'url4.png', href: 'url4.com'
    }];

function ImageChange(target) {
    link.href = images[target].href;
    image.src = images[target].image;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        ImageChange(++target%image.length);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/LdKaw/3/)**

```
<body onload="ImageChange()">
    <div>
        <a id="link" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/Austin-Healey-Photo.jpg" id="image" height="200" width="200"/>
        </a>    
    </div>
</body>


var i = 0;
var img = [
    {
        src:"http://blog.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Siberian-Tiger-Running-Through-Snow-Tom-Brakefield-Getty-Images-200353826-001.jpg",
        href:"http://www.google.com"
    },
    {
        src:"http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/cool-images.jpg",
        href:"http://www.google.com"
    },
    {
        src:"http://blog.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Siberian-Tiger-Running-Through-Snow-Tom-Brakefield-Getty-Images-200353826-001.jpg",
        href:"http://www.google.com"
    },
    {
        src:"http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/images-background.jpg",
        href:"http://www.google.com"
    },
    {
        src:"http://blog.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Simple-Living-Rhiannon-Llewelyn-Taxi-Getty-Images-81938225.jpg",
        href:"http://www.google.com"
    }          
]

function ImageChange(){
    console.log("Source " + i + " : " +document.getElementById("image").src)

    if (i==4){
        i=0;
    }
    i++;
    document.getElementById("image").src=img[i].src;
    document.getElementById("link").href=img[i].href;
    setTimeout("ImageChange()", 2000);
}
```